# Need PHP function to compare two string minus any *special* characters

Tags: php, string, string-comparison

I have two strings:

```
1>  +20122260699
2>  +2012-2260 699
```

I want to test if they're both equal, without counting anything other than the digits 0-9. I know I could use a series of string replaces but is there a more efficient way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Remove all non-numeric characters:
function removeStuff($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str);
}

strcmp( removeStuff($str1), removeStuff($str2) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $str1) == preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $str)) {
  // They're equal, do whatever you want!
}
```

This'll test the two strings stripped of anything other than 0-9.